# JSDoc not detecting class inheritance in JS

Tags: javascript, oop, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I am trying to document my code using JSDoc but I can't figure out how to make it work for it to recognise class inheritance.
Here is a sample code:

```
/**
 * @classdesc Represents a Layer.
 * @class
 * @param {object} satellite - The satellite object.
 * @param {string} date - The image date.
 * 
 * @property {Satellite} satellite - The associated satellite.
 * 
 */
function Layer(satellite, date){

    var self = this;
    self.satellite = satellite;

    /**
     * Compute the water index from RGB imagery.
     * @function compute_wi
     * @memberOf Layer
     * @param {ee.ImageCollection} rgb - RGB imagery.
    */
    self.compute_wi = function(rgb){
        var image = rgb.median();
        return image.normalizedDifference(self.satellite.ndwi_bands);
    };
}


/**
 * @classdesc Class representing a Layer for SAR satellites.
 * @class
 * @augments Layer
 */
function SarLayer(satellite, date, img_layernumber, pre_post){
    Layer.call(this, satellite, date, img_layernumber, pre_post);
    var self = this;
    /**
     * Do nothing (not used for SAR imagery).
     * @function compute_wi
     * @memberOf SarLayer
     * @override
     * @param {ee.ImageCollection} rgb - RGB imagery.
     * @returns {ee.ImageCollection} RGB imagery
    */
    self.compute_wi = function(rgb){
        return rgb;
    };

}
SarLayer.prototype = Object.create(Layer.prototype);
SarLayer.prototype.constructor = SarLayer;
```

In the created JSDoc, I don't see that compute_wi in SARLayer is an overriden function from Layer.
I see the attribute Satellite in the documentation of Layer but not in the one of SARLayer, how can I make it appear there? Same for the other methods that I don't override..

Here is an example of what I expected:
[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLjOu.png)

Here is what I get:
[actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL4Yl.png)

Is it because I declare my methods with the keyword self? Which I need to make class inheritance work (call superclass method when needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to lack the `@instance` type hint that tells the JSDoc these are instance (not static) methods.

Applying the `@instance` to both methods seem to yield the correct output of the documentation generator - I see an **Overrides** together with a link to the base class method (which is what you ask about).

Comment: Oh thanks, it works!
Do you have any ideas on how to make the properties of Layer appear as properties of SARLayer?
Also, is there a way to say that the function has been overridden without copying the whole function documentation. 
i.e. I would like to do 
```
/** 
* @override
*/
```
instead of
```
    /**
     * Do nothing (not used for SAR imagery).
     * @function compute_wi
     * @memberOf SarLayer
     * @override
     * @param {ee.ImageCollection} rgb - RGB imagery.
     * @returns {ee.ImageCollection} RGB imagery
    */
```
Cause most of the stuff is the same.

Comment: Glad this helped, if it works for you please accept this answer as correct. Also, avoid asking additional questions in comments, just create a new question if you wish. Have a nice day.